# VB Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: vb.net, message-queue, message, receiver

```vb
Private Sub Timer2_Tick_1(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    Dim clitLst As New ArrayList()

    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    For Each key In hsClient.Keys
        Dim date1 As Date = Now
        Dim date2 As Date = hsClient(key)
        If DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, date1, date2) > -5 Then
            ListBox1.Items.Add(key.ToString)
            'Error! Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.
            clitLst.Add(key.ToString)
        End If
    Next

    Timer2.Stop()

    Try
        ClstQueue.Receive(New TimeSpan(5))
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try

    ClstQueue.DefaultPropertiesToSend.Label = "Online"
    Dim sumLst As String = String.Join(",", clitLst.ToArray())
    ClstQueue.Send(sumLst)

    ' start timmer
    Timer2.Start()
End Sub
```

Comment: I've got an error at this line clitLst.Add(key.ToString)
how do I fix it?

Comment: If you change your `For Each` to read `For Each key in hsClient.Keys.ToList()` does that fix the problem?

Comment: The problem is partly in code that you don't show.  Somehow, `clitLst.Add` is modifying `hsClient.Keys`.  This is not allowed, and .NET helpfully gives you an error (in my opinion, better than silently corrupting your enumeration).  The suggestion immediately prior is one way to address the problem, as `ToList` will create a copy of the sequence that you iterate, so modifying the original source will no longer break the enumerator.